# Find image path using html

Tags: html, css

This is the path of my html file ie **test.html**

```
/var/www/html/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/test.html
```

i want images from this path:

```
/var/www/html/1/2/3/4
```

How i able to do in img tag, src attribute.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: You can use relative path

Comment: in test.html code, i have image src tag, but file is save in this path: /var/www/html/1/2/3/4.

Comment: See the answer provided by @panther

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Absolute and Relative Paths](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

in your case writing `<img src="."/>` is your current path so it's equivalent to /var/www/html/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/test.html (`.` means current directory)

now you can go some directories up using "`..`" so you can move up to your desired path using this method : `<img src="../../../../../img.jpg">`

These two methods are called Relative paths and that's what you should use in your websites since you can sometimes have to migrate your website and absolute paths wouldn't work anymore

For example if you write 
`<img src="http://html/1/2/3/4/img.jpg"/>` it would still work but only if your site is named "html" and the directory logic stays the same

hope it helped !

Answer (score 1):

Hope i understand your question.
The path should be like this

```
../../../../../img.jpg
```

each `../` will take you back to one folder .. Could you try this..

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path, `..` means *dir up*, so the path in index.html to img.jpg has to be:

```
<img src="../../../../../img.jpg">
```